# How to do mean centering on a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to use two transformation techniques on a data frame, mean centering and standardization. How can I perform the mean centering method on my dataframe?

I have performed standardization using `StandardScaler() from sklearn.preprocessing.`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler()

standard.iloc[:,1:-1] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(standard.iloc[:,1:-1])
```

I am expecting a transformed data frame which is mean-centered

Comment: Hey there, I don't know how to answer this question, but others that will will need to see some sample data and your expected output. please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: What do you mean by mean centering? Any numeric variable by definition is centered on the mean already.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataxx = {'Name':['Tom', 'gik','Tom','Tom','Terry','Jerry','Abel','Dula','Abel'], 
      'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18,88,89,95,96,97],'gg':[1, 1,1, 30, 30,30,40,40,40]} 
dfxx = pd.DataFrame(dataxx)

dfxx["meancentered"] = dfxx.Age - dfxx.Age.mean()
```

| Index | Name | Age | gg | meancentered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tom | 20 | 1 | -40.333333 |
| 1 | gik | 21 | 1 | -39.333333 |
| 2 | Tom | 19 | 1 | -41.333333 |
| 3 | Tom | 18 | 30 | -42.333333 |
| 4 | Terry | 88 | 30 | 27.666667 |
| 5 | Jerry | 89 | 30 | 28.666667 |
| 6 | Abel | 95 | 40 | 34.666667 |
| 7 | Dula | 96 | 40 | 35.666667 |
| 8 | Abel | 97 | 40 | 36.666667 |